# What are the effects of the defensive abilities of the Wild Hunt subtype?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

I looked up the effects but I couldn't find anything. Maybe it's my fault, but I really tried.

What do instinctive cooperation and wild grace do? Do the effects still have to be written? Or are they in some adventure module?

Comment: All the Wild Hunt creatures have those abilities and Wild Hunt is a subtype - or at least it's written like it's supposed to be - so i just assumed those are part of the subtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### They are described on Bestiary 6's Appendix 4.

Starting on page 308, all wild hunt subtype creatures gain:

- Immunity to cold;
- Resistance to fire and electricity 10;
- Enhanced Senses: greensight 60 ft, scent and see in darkness;
- **Instinctive Cooperation**: Immune to all supernatural abilities of other wild hunt creatures that allow a saving throw;
- Planar Acclimation: Always considered to be in their home plane, never gaining the extraplanar subtype;
- Speak with Nature: They have know direction, speak with animals and speak with plants as constant spell-like abilities, and can cast stone tell 3 times per day;
- Wild Gaze: All creatures with 30 ft that fail a will save recognize the wild hunt. Humanoids and monstrous humanoids are paralyzed. Beasts and magical beasts become frightened, and all other creatures become confused. This lasts one round;
- **Wild Grace**: Add their charisma bonus as deflection bonus to AC;
- Wild Hunt Link: May communicate telepathically with other wild hunt creatures within 500 feet and share certain abilities with them.